How to pass argument from gitlab_ci.yml to docker_compose.yml?
I'm new to Gitlab CI and I have a problem in existing project. There's a file VERSION in the root folder which contains version number. I need to:

in the build section of gitlab_ci.yml get version number from file (increment it), then pass it to the Docker container, so I'll be able to access it from code (NET Core, environment variable)
in the deploy section update VERSION file with an incremented number.

What I learned:

I found how to get an incremented version number, but still can't do the docker part - NET Core app still don't have the variable. The problem is that gitlab-ci.yml doesn't have docker build command. I need to pass $VERSION to docker-compose.yml
After googling found out that I can update file in the repository only if I push commit with it and do that with CI skip

gitlab-ci.yml
variables:
  INCREMENTED_VERSION: $(echo $(cat ./VERSION || "1.0.0") | awk -F'.' '{print $1 "." $2 "." $3 + 1}')

stages:
  - build
  - deploy-qa

.backend-build:
  extends: .build-docker-image
  stage: build
  variables:
    DOCKER_DESTINATION: ${CI_REGISTRY}/${DOCKER_IMAGE}:${DOCKER_TAG}
    DOCKER_REGISTRY_REGISTRY: $CI_REGISTRY
    DOCKER_BUILD_CONTEXT: ${CI_PROJECT_DIR}/${BACKEND_SOLUTION_FOLDER}
    DOCKER_DOCKERFILE: ${CI_PROJECT_DIR}/${BACKEND_SOLUTION_FOLDER}/${BACKEND_PROJECT_TO_BUILD}/Dockerfile

.backend-build-matrix: &backend-build-matrix
  parallel:
    matrix:
      - DOCKER_IMAGE: back
        BACKEND_SOLUTION_FOLDER: Server
        BACKEND_PROJECT_TO_BUILD: Server
      - DOCKER_IMAGE: apply-migrations
        BACKEND_SOLUTION_FOLDER: Server
        BACKEND_PROJECT_TO_BUILD: Migrate      

backend-build:
  extends: .backend-build
  <<: *backend-build-matrix

.deploy_qa:
  stage: deploy-qa
  image:
    name: $CI_REGISTRY/deploy-toolkit:$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH
    entrypoint:
      - ""
  needs:
    - backend-build
  before_script:
    - echo ${INCREMENTED_VERSION} ../VERSION

  script:
    - /bin/bash -c "${CI_PROJECT_DIR}/ci-tools/deploy-qa.sh"
  variables:
    BACKEND_HOSTNAME: backend-${CI_DEPLOY_ENVIRONMENT}.${CI_HOSTING_BASE_HOSTNAME}
  environment:
    name: $CI_DEPLOY_ENVIRONMENT
    deployment_tier: testing
    action: start
    url: https://$FRONTEND_HOSTNAME
  resource_group: $CI_DEPLOY_ENVIRONMENT

.deploy_branch_qa:
  extends: .deploy_qa
  variables:
    CI_DEPLOY_ENVIRONMENT: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH
  rules:
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == $CI_DEPLOY_BRANCH

docker-compose.yml
version: "3.9"
services:
    back:
        image: ${REGISTRY_URL}/insiders.back:${IMAGE_TAG}
        restart: unless-stopped
        build: 
            context: ./Server
            dockerfile: Server/Dockerfile
        environment:
            ConnectionStrings__DefaultConnection: ${CONNECTION_STRING}
            VERSION: ${INCREMENTED_VERSION}
        volumes:
          - ${BACK_VAULT_CONFIG}:/workdir/VaultConfig.json
          - ${BACK_CONFIG}:/workdir/appsettings.json
        ports:
          - ${API_PORT}:80
        networks:
        - insiders
networks:
    insiders:
      driver: bridge

dockerfile
ARG BASE_IMAGE=cr.yandex/crposeu72p2knoi3ptnc/dotnet/aspnet:6.0
ARG BUILD_IMAGE=cr.yandex/crposeu72p2knoi3ptnc/dotnet/sdk:6.0

FROM ${BASE_IMAGE} AS base
WORKDIR /workdir
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

FROM ${BUILD_IMAGE} AS build
ARG NUGET_REPO=https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json
ENV NUGET_REPO ${NUGET_REPO}
ARG VERSION=1.0.0
ENV VERSION 
WORKDIR /workdir
COPY "Server/Server.csproj" "Server/"
COPY . .
RUN dotnet restore "Server/Server.csproj" -s ${NUGET_REPO}
RUN dotnet build "Server/Server.csproj"  -c Release -o ./app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "Server/Server.csproj"  -c Release -o ./app/publish

FROM base AS production
WORKDIR /workdir
COPY "Server/Templates" /workdir/Templates
COPY --from=publish /workdir/app/publish .
COPY Server/appsettings.json .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "Server.dll"]

